# XML Library Suggestions

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but here goes…

I have an XML file that I want to read. Thus far, I have been using `lxml.etree.ElementTree`. However, I find that I need functionality that allows me to travel from a child node, to its parent node in the XML.

This seems to be not possible with `lxml.etree.ElementTree`. Is there an xml parsing library that will allow me to do this?

In case it matters, I'm on Python 2.7.3

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`s do not keep track of parent elements, but `lxml.etree._Element`s do:

```
parent = elt.getparent()
```

---

For example,

```
import lxml.etree as ET
# import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
text = '''\
<root>
<foo>
    <bar/>
    <bar/>
</foo>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(text)
for elt in root.findall('foo/bar'):
    parent = elt.getparent()
    print(parent)
```

yields

```
<Element foo at 0xb7415c34>
<Element foo at 0xb7415c34>
```

Comment: How can I get an `lxml.etree.ElementTree._Element` from `lxml.etree.ElementTree.parse(…).getroot()` (which is how I start the parsing process)?

Comment: `ET.parse(...).getroot()` returns a `lxml.etree._Element`. (Note, there is not such thing as `lxml.etree.ElementTree._Element`...)

Comment: I get `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` as the type of `root`. Perhaps there's a version difference. I'm on lxml version 3.1.2. Thoughts?

Comment: Hm, I guess so. I'm using version 2.3.0. Have you tried `getparent()`? [The documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) still says it should work. (Search down for the string `getparent`). Note though, on the root element it will return `None`...

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Time to install the older version (blergh!)

Comment: The problem was that I was using `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`, which, as it turns out, is not the same as `import lxml.etree as ET`. Using the former gets me an `Element`, while the latter gets me an `_Element`, as needed

Comment: Ah, I see. I just finished installing 3.2.0. The API seems to work as advertised, as long as you `import lxml.etree as ET`